# How to get font smoothing to work in Firefox under Linux?

Tags: linux, fonts, kde, kde-4

I'm using Arch Linux with KDE 4.6 and Firefox 5.0, and I had to install a GTK+ theme to make apps like Firefox look nicer.

Now, I have another problem—Firefox doesn't use font smoothing on sites, even though KDE itself uses font smoothing. I didn't see anything related to that in settings.

Comment: tried http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=849523 ?

Comment: @Sathya It didn't work. I'm using Firefox 5 if that matters.

Comment: Try disabling hardware acceleration, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved the problem by removing `ttf-ms-fonts` and `ttf-vista-fonts` and installing higher quality fonts (`ttf-ubuntu-font-family` and `otf-texgyre`) from the AUR.

Answer (score 1):

Does the article [Enable Smooth fonts on Ubuntu Linux](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/enable-smooth-fonts-on-ubuntu-linux/) apply to your case ?

It is also possible that your problem relates to [Bug 660448 - Subpixel antialiasing too strong/incorrect everywhere](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=660448), which was marked fixed on 2011-07-05. If so, then a future version of Firefox will fix the problem. You could also verify against [Firefox Nightly Builds](http://nightly.mozilla.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If it is indeed only happening on certain fonts, you can create a `.fonts.conf` file in your home directory with the following:

```
<fontconfig>
  <match target="font">
    <edit name="embeddedbitmap" mode="assign">
      <bool>false</bool>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

You may need to regenerate your font cache and/or restart X for this change to take effect.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, but I solved the problem—as you see in my answer.